# Unable to use "socket" in my vscode using python

Tags: python, sockets

I was just learning socket programming in python and was unable to run my socket commands in vs code.

the code i wrote is:-

```
import socket

import threading

PORT=5050

SERVER =socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname) 
print(SERVER)
```

The code produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Gurkirat Singh\Desktop\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import socket

  File "c:\Users\Gurkirat Singh\Desktop\socket.py", line 3, in <module>
    from xmlrpc.client import Server

  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 136, in <module>
    import http.client

  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", 
line 789, in <module>
    class HTTPConnection:

  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", 
line 837, in HTTPConnection

    def __init__(self, host, port=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'socket' has no attribute '_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your stack trace, you seem to have a file named `socket.py`:

```
File "c:\Users\Gurkirat Singh\Desktop\socket.py", line 3, in <module>
    from xmlrpc.client import Server
```

Having a file named `socket.py` in your workspace causes import problems because Python won't import its library module `socket` but instead will import your own file.

Rename your file from `socket.py` to something else like `mysock.py` and delete anything from your `Desktop` directory called `socket.pyc` if it exists.

Comment: Also, ```SERVER =socket.gethostbyname() ``` takes a string.
try, SERVER =socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())